# How to correctly configure the parser & plugins with ESLint's new Flat-config?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-flat-config

### How does one go about configuring ESLint using the new Flat-Config system *(aka `eslint.config.js` file)* such that it works with the @TypeScript-ESLint/ESLint-plugin & TypeScript parser?

---

—

ESLint's new configuration system, **["Flat Config"](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-1/)** allows for multiple rule-sets in a single configuration file. This makes overriding rules much easier than using the cascading file-system concept that ESLint implements in its original configuration system. Because I have to add support for both ESM & CJS when I publish a package to NPM, the Flat-config is like a dream come true, as it will allow me to use ESLint in a far more simple manner.

The only problem is I cannot get ESLint's new configuration system to work with any plug-ins, and on the opposite side of the coin, I cannot get plugins to work with flat-config.

When Linting TypeScript using ESLint, its pretty important to equip the 2 plug-ins I listed below. Those two plug-ins implement rules that allows typescript to be able to lint TypeScript code bases correctly. Its imperative that I have them.

- ...the TypeScript-ESLint Parser [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser)
- & the TypeScript-ESLint Plugin [@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin)

2BH I am all over the place with my configuration file, currently it looks like the example bellow, but the example just shows my latest desperate attempt, I have tried all sorts of things.

```
import eslintPlugin from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'

export default [
  {
    files: ["src/**/*.ts", "src/main.cts", "src/main.mts"],
    ignores: ["**/*.d.*", "**/*.map.*", "**/*.js", "**/*.mjs", "**/*.cjs"],
    plugins: { eslintPlugin },

    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: "latest",
      sourceType: "module",
      parser: "eslintPlugin/parser",
    },

    rules: {
      semi: "error",
      quotes: ["error", "single"],
      indent: [
        "error",
        2,
        {
          SwitchCase: 1,
          VariableDeclarator: "first",
          ImportDeclaration: "first",
          ArrayExpression: "first",
          ObjectExpression: "first",
          CallExpression: { arguments: "first" },
          FunctionDeclaration: { body: 1, parameters: 4 },
          FunctionExpression: { body: 1, parameters: 4 },
        },
      ],
    },
  },

];
```

---

I also use the TypeScript plugin **[TypeScript ESLint Language Service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-eslint-language-service)** plug-in. I don't like when TypeScript & ESLint report the same errors, so I don't use any extension for ESLint, but I do integrate a build system that lints my project as work on, and the errors found by ESLint are reported through the TSC compiler.

The problem is the same though, I cannot get the *"TypeScript/ESLint language service"* plug-in to work with the new ESLint Configuration System (aka flat-config).

---

If anyone knows how to configure eslint using the eslint.config.js flat config file so that it works with the typescript/eslint plug-ins (plug-ins for eslint) &/or the *"TS Language Service"* plugin (plugin for typescript) I would like if you could show me what that configuration looks like.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Im using flat config with typescript. Heres what I think are the important parts of the config:

```js
import ts from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin';
import tsParser from '@typescript-eslint/parser';
import functional from 'eslint-plugin-functional';
import imprt from 'eslint-plugin-import'; // 'import' is ambiguous & prettier has trouble


...


    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: { modules: true },
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        project: './tsconfig.json',
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      functional,
      import: imprt,
      '@typescript-eslint': ts,
      ts,
    },

...

    rules: {
      ...ts.configs['eslint-recommended'].rules,
      ...ts.configs['recommended'].rules,

      'ts/return-await': 2,
```

Take note that the ts plugin is there twice. The shared configs use the longer namespace than what I wanted to use.

Comment: Awesome tom, I am going to try this right now.

Comment: I am guessing `functional` & `import: imprt` are other plugins you're using?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Added the two import statements to help clarify.

Comment: Thanks for this. One note: The "eslint-recommended" config contains an "overrides" array with the rules, I got it working with
```
rules: {
      ...ts.configs['eslint-recommended'].overrides[0].rules,
...
```

Comment: I don't think you need `ts,` under `plugins` when you have `'@typescript-eslint': ts,`. Except this lets you refer to the rules with `ts/some-rule-name` instead of `@typescript-eslint/some-rule-name`: https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#personalized-plugin-namespaces but keeping only one of them makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me but I still find the API to be rather verbose.

```js
const tsPlugin = require("@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin");
const tsParser = require("@typescript-eslint/parser");

const tsOverrideConfig = tsPlugin.configs["eslint-recommended"].overrides[0];
const tsRecommemdedConfig = tsPlugin.configs.recommended;
const files = ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"];

module.exports = [
  "eslint:recommended",
  {
    files,
    linterOptions: {
      reportUnusedDisableDirectives: true,
    },
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
    },
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": tsPlugin,
    },
  },
  { files, rules: tsOverrideConfig.rules },
  { files, rules: tsRecommemdedConfig.rules },
];
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know it could be done using `require("@npm-id/package").

Answer (score 6):

Here is my working flat `eslint.config.mjs` with the following key points:

- supports [Typescript parser and plugin](https://typescript-eslint.io/)
- enables Node.js and Mocha [globals](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#goodbye-environments%2C-hello-globals)
- uses ESM format (even for CJS projects)

```js
import globals from "globals";
import tsParser from "@typescript-eslint/parser";
import tsPlugin from "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin";
import eslintJsPlugin from "@eslint/js";

export default [
  {
    rules: eslintJsPlugin.configs.recommended.rules,
  },
  {
    files: [ "**/*.ts" ],
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
      globals: globals.node,
    },
    plugins: {
      "@typescript-eslint": tsPlugin,
    },
    rules: {
      ...tsPlugin.configs.recommended.rules,
      "no-console": "error",
    }
  },
  {
    files: [ "test/**/*.ts" ],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: globals.mocha,
    },
  },
];
```

To run eslint with this config in CommonJS project I use the [following command](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/16580#issuecomment-1338211234):

```
ESLINT_USE_FLAT_CONFIG=true npx eslint src test
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [flatConfig example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/tree/main/playgrounds/flatConfig) in [microsoft/vscode-eslint](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) repository (➜ VSCode [ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)).

**Example:**
[eslint.config.js](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/blob/747efb780e024eabc48b67ca68a2f8a0c594b753/playgrounds/flatConfig/eslint.config.js)

```js
const globals = require('globals');
const typescriptParser =  require('@typescript-eslint/parser');
const typescriptPlugin = require('@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin');

module.exports = [
    "eslint:recommended",
    {
        files: ["**/*.js"],
        languageOptions: {
            parserOptions: {
                sourceType: "module"
            },
            globals: {
                ...globals.browser,
                ...globals.node,
                ...globals.es6,
                ...globals.commonjs
            }
        },
    },
    {
        files: ["sub/*.js"],
        rules: {
            "no-undef": "warn",
            "no-console": "warn"
        }
    },
    {
        files: ["*.ts", "**/*.ts"],
        plugins: {
            "@typescript-eslint": typescriptPlugin
        },
        languageOptions: {
            parser: typescriptParser,
            parserOptions: {
                project: "./tsconfig.json",
                sourceType: "module",
                ecmaVersion: 2020
            }
        },
        rules: {
            "semi": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/semi": "error",
            "no-extra-semi": "warn",
            "curly": "warn",
            "quotes": ["error", "single", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true } ],
            "eqeqeq": "error",
            "indent": "off",
            "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["warn", "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 } ],
            "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error"
        }
    }
]
```

###### ESLint blog posts (flat config):

1. [ESLint's new config system, Part 1: Background](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-1/)
2. [ESLint's new config system, Part 2: Introduction to flat config](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/) (most interesting)
3. [ESLint's new config system, Part 3: Developer preview](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-3/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps worth mentioning ***typescript-eslint*** suggests another approach in defining their eslint Flat Config:

Example: `eslint.config.js`

```
// @ts-check

import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
);
```

https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/